# How to add custom text to a cell based on a specific entry in a different cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

My laboratory is capable of running 20+ different analyses, and we get contracts from about the same 15 companies to do a combination of these analyses. I created an Excel spread sheet to keep track of the work as it comes in, where columns are the 20 different analyses we can run, and rows are the companies. I type in either a checkmark or "NA", depending on whether that company requests that specific analysis. (Each company requests its own combination of analyses).

I need some help with the following:

If I enter "Company 1" in cell A100, I want cell B100 to display "NA". If I enter "Company 2" instead, I want cell D100 to display "NA". And if I enter "Company 3", do nothing, for example. I am OK with adding the check marks manually, as there are other variables that need not be mentioned.

Now, I have been able to develop some toy solution in VBA to some extent (please see code below). However, I have two issues:

1. In order to run the code, I have to switch to the VBA editor and press F5 after every entry. Instead, I would like it to work like when using formulas for the cells. In other words, if I type in "Company 1" in any cell of column A and hit "Enter", I would like the "NA" to display automatically in the appropriate cells on the row. I guess I could record a macro for this, but the file is shared with many people and I would prefer to avoid that.
2. In the future I will need to add more companies and analyses, so I need a code I can quickly go in and update. Or maybe have a list of companies that I add to and link it somehow to my code.

   ```
   Sub writeNA()
   For i = 1 To 20 Step 1

   x = Cells(i, 1).Value

   If x = "Company 1" Then
    Cells(i, 2).Value = "NA"
   End If

   If x = "Company 2" Then
    Cells(i, 3).Value = "NA"
   End If

   If x = "Company 3" Then
    Cells(i, 4).Value = "NA"
   End If

   Next
   End Sub
   ```

Thank you!

Comment: @user65202 ,, this code is working properly,, to get rid of running from VB editor,, better create one COMMAND button and use the code through button,, for Company 3 replace NA with Blank space !! Another should IF and Formula !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with formulas, ***so long as you do not need to edit the results***

- Create a table that serves as a template for the various companies.

  - This can be on a separate worksheet, which you can even hide if you want.
- `NAME` the table, for example: `tblTests`

It might look like:

[image]

- Set up your working sheet similarly, with column A being where you fill in the company name, and a list of the tests across the top.
- In `B2` of the working sheet, enter the formula:

**for O365** :

`=IFERROR(FILTER(tblTests[[Test1]:[Test20]],tblTests[Company]=A2),"")`

**for earlier versions:**

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(tblTests[[Test1]:[Test20]],MATCH(A4,tblTests[Company],0),0),"")
```

and fill down as far as needed.

*(If your Excel version does not have dynamic arrays, you may need to enter it as an array formula across the entire row segment of 20 cells)*

If you now enter a Company name in column A, it will automatically fill in the row with the pattern you set up.

[image]

If this **MUST** be a macro, or if you may ***need to modify the cells after filling them in***, you can use a similar approach, with a macro referencing a lookup table that you've set up either in your workbook, or code, and have the macro fired by an `worksheet_change` event targeting column A

For example, enter the code below as `Worksheet Code` for the worksheet where you are logging the companies: *(note that we are still using a template table on some worksheet in the workbook)*

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim R As Range, C As Range, V, I As Long, J As Long
    Dim tblTests As Variant

Set R = Columns(1)
Set C = Intersect(Target, R)
If Not C Is Nothing Then
    If C.Count > 1 Then
        MsgBox "Enter only one company at a time"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'tblTests is on Sheet1
    tblTests = Sheet1.ListObjects("tblTests").DataBodyRange
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        With C
            Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(1, 21)).ClearContents
                'with only 20 companies, can loop the table
                'if you have thousands, may be more efficient to read the lookup table into a dictionary
                I = 1
                Do Until tblTests(I, 1) = C.Value
                    I = I + 1
                    If I > UBound(tblTests, 1) Then Exit Do
                Loop
                
                If I > UBound(tblTests, 1) Then
                    If Len(C) > 0 Then .Offset(0, 1) = "Company not in template table"
                Else
                    ReDim V(1 To 21)
                    For J = 1 To 21
                        V(J) = tblTests(I, J)
                    Next J
                    
                    .Resize(columnsize:=21) = V
                End If
            End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for very comprehensive answer! I will be able to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

I think, I have not understood, otherwise to me it appears as a simple formula

In B100 you enter formula ,  = IF(A100="Company 1","NA","")

In D100 you enter the formula, = IF(A100="Company 2","NA","")

Thanks.

Comment: Well no, the problem was that there would be a combination on "NAs" based on Company analyses requests. As can be seen above, a good strategy is to have a sort of template, as long as the Companies keep their analysis requests constant.